# Does drush up do a database backup/dump?

Tags: database, drush

Does running `drush up` run a database backup? From testing, it looks like it doesn't. Should I be doing a separate database backup before I run `drush up` to update?

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/complete-backup-solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it doesn't. It only makes a backup of the current module directories, before it replaces them.

To create a sql dump, use

```
drush sql-dump > filename.sql.
```

But remember to move the file outside of your webroot.

Comment: I would like to remind people to do a dump outside of your website root; so hackers will stay away.

Comment: This "accepted" answer is not correct. Drush in fact does provide a dump of the database:   "drush sql-dump"
http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/sql/sql-dump/

Comment: Um. Try reading the answer again. All of it, not just the first sentence. Because that's exactly what I wrote. The question was if "drush up" does it, not if drush can do it.

Answer (score 10):

To make [gzipped mysql dump with drush](https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/sql_dump):

`drush sql-dump --gzip --result-file={PATH-TO-RESULT-FILE}`

*Update from the wranvaud's comment:*
If you don't specify the result file it will be stored on you home folder under: `~/drush-backups/<db_name>/<timestamp>/<database_file>.sql.gz`, otherwise you can specify --result-file='~/Documents/<my_backups_folder>'

Comment: if you don't specify the result file it will be stored on you home folder under ~/drush-backups/<db_name>/<timestamp>/<database_file>.sql.gz otherwise you can specify `--result-file='~/Documents/<my_backups_folder>'`

Answer (score 5):

If you have the [Backup and Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module installed, you can call it from Drush with

`$ drush bam-backup`

Comment: drush natively supports a database dump, without the need for an extra module, see above

Answer (score 2):

This is a bash script solution to Backup and Restore from command line with **drush** and **[Acquia-Drupal](http://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-drupal)**:

- ***Note:** You only have to change basepath,sitename and maybe drushpath in both scripts to fit your needs*
- ***Note 2:** The Backup script will create a .tar containing your site files plus a data.sql file describing your database*
- ***Note3:** The restore script will chose the last .tar backup file created by the backup script*

### **INSTRUCTIONS**

1) Find the drush path (drush is included in acquia), in my case (drushpath="/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush")

2) Create a backup_*mysite* file and a restore_*mysite* file and
    include them in your bin folder path (for example: /usr/local/bin)

3) Edit **backup_*mysite***

```
#!/bin/bash
# Text color variables
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow

basepath="path-to-your-server-root" #4ex "/Users/monojones/www"
backuppath="$basepath/backups"
drushpath="/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush"
sitename="your-sitename"
tempdir="$backuppath/backup_$sitename"

if [ -d $backuppath ]; then
 echo "Backup path finded. [ $backuppath ]"
else
  echo "Creating backup path... [ $backuppath ]"
  mkdir $backuppath
fi

echo "${txtylw}Backing up $sitename ... ${txtgrn}"
if [ -d "$backuppath/$sitename" ]; then
 echo "Backup subdir finded."
else
 echo "Creating $backuppath/$sitename" 
 mkdir $backuppath/$sitename
fi
echo "${txtylw}"
mkdir $tempdir
$drushpath/drush -r $basepath/$sitename  sql-dump --result-file=$tempdir/data.sql
tar -pczf $tempdir/files.tgz $basepath/$sitename $systempaths
tar -pczf $backuppath/$sitename/$sitename.backup_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).tar.gz $tempdir
rm -rf $tempdir
```

4) Edit **restore_*mysite***

```
#!/bin/bash
# Text color variables
txtred=$(tput setaf 1)    # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow

basepath="path-to-your-server-root" #4ex "/Users/monojones/www"
backuppath="$basepath/backups"
sitename="your-sitename"
drushpath="/Applications/acquia-drupal/drush"

echo "${txtylw}Restoring ${txtred}$sitename ${txtylw} database: ${txtgrn}"
FILE=`ls -1 $backuppath/$sitename/$sitename.backup_* | tail -n 1`
echo "Last backup file: ${txtpur} $FILE ${txtylw}"
mkdir temp_drupalbackup_$sitename 
tar -C temp_drupalbackup_$sitename -zxvf $FILE ${backuppath:1}/backup_$sitename/data.sql
$drushpath/drush sql-drop
drush sql-cli <  temp_drupalbackup_$sitename/${backuppath:1}/backup_$sitename/data.sql
rm -R temp_drupalbackup_$sitename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sql-sync for backup.

```
$ drush sql-sync -v @site1 @site2
```

Comment: This is the best way to back up a site.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy now with Drush 5

“Note: Drush 5 introduced archive-dump and archive-restore commands which allow you to backup your code, files, and database into a single file."

https://drupal.org/upgrade/backing-your-site-command-line